# FreeFrom recipient's name is a zero

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

When sending email notifications to users via FreeForm, the recipient's name is a zero; see screenshot. Looking at the documentation, it doesn't appear I can set the recipient's name in the heading comment block. Thoughts on why this "0" is appearing as the user's name? Is there any way to override it?

[image: screenshot]